# Making my regular expression work (regex101 link included)

Tags: regex

https://regex101.com/r/t6pBFQ/2

I need only matches which contain WARNING:. I made some groups to identify device tag names and block tag names. Also I need text of warnings as a group. Thanks!

Regex:

`(Device Tag name: )([^ ]+)\s+(Block Tag Name: )([^ ]+)([\s\S]+?)Completed Block Parameter Uploading\.`

Text:

`Device Tag name: 002LT002   Block Tag name: TRANSDUCE_T03-01(TRANSDUCER_03)
  Start Block Parameter Uploading.
  Acquire Live List.
  Confirm Device to be loaded.
  Initiate connecting for Application.
  Upload Block Parameter. Block ID = TRANSDUCER_03
  Disconnect
  Completed Block Parameter Uploading.
Device Tag name: 002LT002   Block Tag name: 002LIA002_30(AI_01)
  Start Block Parameter Uploading.
  Acquire Live List.
  Confirm Device to be loaded.
  Initiate connecting for Application.
  Upload Block Parameter. Block ID = AI_01
WARNING:Invalid Parameter Value of Block ID (AI_01) and Parameter Name (XD_SCALE.DECIMAL) (This parameter is a drawing setting item).  Data Value=Actual Device:0, Setting Data:2
  Disconnect
  Completed Block Parameter Uploading.`

Comment: You should put your RegEx and (some of) the test string in the question itself. People won't want to click on the regex101 link.

Comment: It would be nice if you'd give us an example of what is expected.

Comment: I think that it's great that you linked to regex101.com.

Answer (score 0):

This pattern `([\s\S]+?)` will match any character including newlines no greedy but it is not taking WARNING into account.

To only match the block which contain `WARNING:` you could first match all the lines   before warning and make sure that they don't start with `Completed Block Parameter Uploading` because that is the end of one block.

Then make sure WARNING: is matched and continue matching until you do match `Completed Block Parameter Uploading`

```
(Device Tag name: )([^ ]+)\s+(Block Tag Name: )([^ ]+)(?:\n(?!\s+Completed Block Parameter Uploading).*)+\s+WARNING:(.*(?:\n.*))\s+Completed Block Parameter Uploading\.
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/7EZ7E1/1)

If you don't need the capturing  groups at the start you could [omit those](https://regex101.com/r/7EZ7E1/2) leaving you only with 1 capturing group for the WARNING message.

I have replaced `([\s\S]+?)Completed Block Parameter Uploading\.` with:

- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `\n(?!\s+Completed Block Parameter Uploading).*` Match a newline and the rest of the string and assert that what is on the right is not the last line of a block
- `)+` Close non capturing group and repeat 1+ times
- `\s+WARNING:` Match 1+ whitespace characters and WARNING:
- `(.*(?:\n.*))` Capture group for the warning message
- `\s+Completed Block Parameter Uploading\.` Match en last line of block